# In App Purchase You already own this item error

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have two phones with same user account. and subscribed a product from one device. when i trying to subscribe the same in next device it shows error message as "You already own this item" . I need to subscribe the same two devices concurrently. How it can possible ? I am using V3 api for billing. Is there any restriction , that is only one subscription per one account or something like that ? Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

All the purchases you make are synced across all the devices which are logged in with same google account i.e. if you make a purchase on 1 device that purchase will be available with you on all other devices which are configured to same google account and if you try to purchase the same item again IAP takes care of that and won't let you do that.
Still if you want to purchase the an item multiple time(like any healthpack in case of a game) then you need to inform playstore about the consumption of that item even if you haven't consumed it and in that case you need to keep track of that item yourself(use servers to keep track of the items)

check this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=DgcJPIRpfSk